# CakePHP 2.x: Paginação com Query Personalizada

Tags: cakephp-2

Muito bati a cabeça até o momento para tentar compreender como funciona a paginação do CakePHP com Custom Query's mais não tive muito sucesso. Este é o método que tenho atualmente, quero fazer uma paginação em cima dele, como utilizar o `Paginator` nessa situação?

```
    function search(){
    $this->layout = 'mpf';
    $fields = array('Convenio.*','tbl_agencias.gerev');
    $join = array(  
        array(
            'table' => 'tbl_agencias',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array('Convenio.centralizadora = tbl_agencias.id')
        )
    );
    $conditions = array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Convenio.nome LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Convenio']['search']."%",
            'Convenio.centralizadora' => $this->request->data['Convenio']['search'],
            'Convenio.id' => $this->request->data['Convenio']['search'],
        ),
        array(
            'AND' => array(
                'Convenio.situacao != ' => '-1'
            )
        )
    );
    $group = array('Convenio.nome');
    $this->set('convenios', $this->Convenio->find('all',array('fields'=>$fields,'conditions'=>$conditions,'joins'=>$join,'group'=>$group)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que foi mesmo só falta de interpretação.
Bastava passar o parâmetros como se fosse no próprio `find()`

Ficou assim:

```
   function search(){
        $this->layout = 'mpf';
        $fields = array('Convenio.*','tbl_agencias.gerev');
        $join = array(  
            array(
                'table' => 'tbl_agencias',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array('Convenio.centralizadora = tbl_agencias.id')
            )
        );
        $conditions = array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Convenio.nome LIKE' => "%".$this->request->data['Convenio']['search']."%",
                'Convenio.centralizadora' => $this->request->data['Convenio']['search'],
                'Convenio.id' => $this->request->data['Convenio']['search'],
            ),
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'Convenio.situacao != ' => '-1'
                )
            )
        );
        $group = array('Convenio.nome');
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'fields' => $fields,
            'joins' => $join,
            'group' => $group,
            'limit' => 25
        );
        $convenios = $this->Paginator->paginate('Convenio');
        $this->set(compact('convenios'));
        //$this->set('convenios', $this->Convenio->find('all',array('fields'=>$fields,'conditions'=>$conditions,'joins'=>$join,'group'=>$group)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub - Exemplo prático de find customizado com cakephp](https://gist.github.com/rederlo/0aaa99abc503f34941ae)

Caro AComerlatto espero que ajude, esse exemplo é dos muitos métodos escritos para suprir necessidades mais elaboradas.